# Using JSON in AngularJS REST

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest

This is silly question. I am calling rest service from Angular like that:

```
UserService.GetByUsername(username)
    .then(function (user) {
        if (user !== null && user.password === password) {

                        response = { success: true };
...
```

I can see from the debugger that there really is a user object with proper value from DB:

```
{
firstName: "Suba",
lastName: "Superi",
lastUpdated: "2015-06-02T18:14:56+03:00",
nickName: "",
password: "super",
userId: 2,
username: "super"
}
```

**Question**

Why this (`user.password`) is undefined: `if (user !== null && user.password === password)`. Is there something in my notation or how can I check if password from DB is the same than user inputed in form? How can I get that password from JSON returned from rest, json parse maybe? I just started AngularJS and to implement authentication and login, so don't bother even password are plain text etc :) This is just annoying me. User is an object, I think that this is the reason, cause I assume that it is type of user?

Comment: Are you sure that `user.password` is `undefined`? If anything `password` would be `undefined`. I don't see where `password` is defined.

Comment: Post your service code too.

Comment: password is from form and user is from db. I checked it with chrome debugger and user is not null and there is correct object, but user.password is still undefined as a whole, password is getting correct value as well.

Comment: You've made a (probably small) mistake somewhere. You aren't giving enough information to help.

Comment: Thanks @Andy Gaskell as well for helping me. It was a really small and silly mistake and basically it was just because of naming response as a user and it confused me.  user.data.password or response.data.password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you are getting the "user" object and not the response object in the then() ?

```
UserService.GetByUsername(username)
    .then(function (response) {
        if (response && response.data && response.data.password === password) {
```

Comment: Thank you, I got a response object, NOT a user. That was it. I just changed this: UserService.GetByUsername(username)
                    .then(function (user) {        
                                if (user !== null && user.data.password === password) {